# Determining spot price differential equation from future contract process

Tags: stochastic-calculus

In appendix A of [Valuing Energy Options in a One Factor Model Fitted to Forward Prices](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=D994BA66A4F6D95D335A8012C1AB7124?doi=10.1.1.28.7952&rep=rep1&type=pdf)  by Les Clewlow and Chris Strickland they develop a stochastic differential equation of spot prices exploiting the relationship between Forwards and Spot prices i.e $S(t) = F(t,t)$. In simple terms, this means that the price of a future contract that delivers a good at time t for a future time t ($F(t,t)$) must be equal to the price of the good at time t ($S(t)$)

They define the following stochastic differential equation for the futures contract:
$$
\frac{dF(t,T)}{F(t,T)} = \sigma(t,T)dW(t)
$$

With a bit of ito calculus it is not very hard to obtain the solution for F(t,T) as
$$
F(t,T) = F(0,T)exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t} \sigma(u,T)^2 du + \int_{0}^{t} \sigma(u,T)dW(u)\right)
$$

I we now exploit the relationship $S(t) = F(t,t)$ we can obtain the following equation:

$$
S(t) = F(0,t)exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t} \sigma(u,t)^2 du + \int_{0}^{t} \sigma(u,t)dW(u)\right)
$$

they then go ahead and state that by differentiation you can obtain the following expression for $S(t)$

$$
\frac{dS(t)}{S(t)} = \left[\frac{\partial lnF(0,t)}{\partial t} - \int_{0}^{t} \sigma(u,t) \frac{\partial \sigma(u,t)}{\partial t} du + \int_{0}^{t} \frac{\partial \sigma(u,t)}{\partial t}dW(u)\right]dt + \sigma(t,t)dW(t)
$$

I am really struggling to do the derivation of this last equation. Can someone help me with the intuition behind it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mere application of Itô's lemma, but I must admit that the notation may turn out to be confusing because of two reasons. The first one is the presence of two different times, namely the time $t$ measuring the evolution of the stochastic process and the term $T$, which appear to coincide after some step, while the considered bivariate functions still treat them separately. The second reason is, I guess, the ambiguous notation $\int_0^t \ldots \mathrm{d}W_u$, which means $\int_{W_0}^{W_t} \ldots \mathrm{d}W_u$ actually.

Let's rewrite the quantity $S(t)$ by taking those ambiguities into account. Firstly, let's recall that $F(t,T)$ is a stochastic process, where $t$ is the real "passing" time and $T$ is just a parameter. Let's denote the dependence of processes on the time $t$ by a subscript, in the same manner as $W_t$, hence $F_t(T)$. In the same spirit, one has $S_t = F_t(t)$, where the second $t$ is still treated as a parameter, which appears to be equal to $t$ "by coincidence". Thus, we understand that $F_0(t)$ is only an initial condition with respect to the process, even if it is dependent on $t$ as a parameter; in consenquence, $F_0(t)$ will be later differentiated with respect to $t$ as a mere function and not as a stochastic process; in other words, we will get its differential with the help of a partial derivative instead of Itô's lemma, even it is a random variable.

Moreover, $S_t$ is also a function of a Brownian motion, so that $S_t = f(W_t,t)$, where
$$
f(x,t) = F_0(t)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sigma_u(t)^2 \mathrm{d}u + \int_0^x \sigma_u(t) \mathrm{d}W_u\right).
$$
Then, Itô's lemma is applied as usual, i.e. $\mathrm{d}S_t = \left(\partial_tf(W_t,t) + \partial_xf(W_t,t) + \frac{1}{2}\partial_x^2f(W_t,t)\right)\mathrm{d}t + \partial_xf(W_t,t)\mathrm{d}W_t$. Since the variables appear inside the integrals too, we must use Leibniz integral rule, hence :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
\partial_tf(W_t,t) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   F_0(t)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sigma_u(t)^2 \mathrm{d}u + \int_0^{W_t} \sigma_u(t) \mathrm{d}W_u\right) \cdot \left(\frac{\partial_tF_0(t)}{F_0(t)} - \frac{1}{2}\sigma_t(t)^2 - \int_0^t \sigma_u(t)\partial_t\sigma_u(t) \mathrm{d}u + \int_0^{W_t} \partial_t\sigma_u(t) \mathrm{d}W_u\right) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   S_t\left(\partial_t\ln F_0(t) - \frac{1}{2}\sigma_t(t)^2 - \int_0^t \sigma_u(t)\partial_t\sigma_u(t) \mathrm{d}u + \int_0^{W_t} \partial_t\sigma_u(t) \mathrm{d}W_u\right)
\end{array}
$$
where the parentheses on the right contains the derivative of the argument of the exponential, while
$$
\partial_xf(W_t,t) = F_0(t)\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t \sigma_u(t)^2 \mathrm{d}u + \int_0^{W_t} \sigma_u(t) \mathrm{d}W_u\right) \cdot \sigma_t(t) = S_t\sigma_t(t),
$$
and
$$\partial_x^2f(W_t,t) = S_t\sigma_t(t)^2$$ in consequence. After collecting all the terms, we get :
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}S_t}{S_t} = \left(\partial_t\ln F_0(t) - \int_0^t \sigma_u(t)\partial_t\sigma_u(t) \mathrm{d}u + \int_0^{W_t} \partial_t\sigma_u(t) \mathrm{d}W_u\right)\mathrm{d}t + \sigma_t(t)\mathrm{d}W_t
$$

And hence this is the full derivation of the stochastic differential equation.

Comment: Thanks, Abezhiko. This makes a lot of sense. I need to review the derivation inside the integrals! Also, I've just realized that I could have taken the $lnF(0,t)$ into the exponential and I would get the initial condition!
Re the $-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_t(t)^2$ I believe this cancels out because you have a dependence on $S_t$ on the first derivate. That means that the second derivate still had a dependence on x. Hence: 
$$
\partial^2_x f(W_t,t) = S_t \sigma_t(t)^2
$$

Comment: one last question... when taking derivatives with respect to time in $\int_{0}^{W_t} \sigma_u(t)dW_u$ you only have the derivative inside the integral. I guess this is because when applying the Leibniz rule the derivative of $W_t $ with respect to $t$ is $0$

Comment: I've edited your answer to include the result of my first comment and approved it as the main answer. Thanks for your help Abezhiko!

Comment: @konnoc84  I'm a bit late to the party, thank you for the editing work.